# Serve physical JSON files with .json file extension using ServiceStack

Tags: json, angularjs, servicestack

I am trying to get a static .json file from my angular $http request, but it appears ServiceStack has a handle on all *.json requests.  Is it possible to GET a physical json file?

Here is the error I get:

```
Forbidden

Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.PathInfo: /app/resources/menu/administrator.json
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /app/resources/menu/administrator.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ServiceStack only serves static files with [pre-configured safe file extensions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/HostConfig.cs#L74).

You can add static`.json` files to the allowed white-list with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    AllowFileExtensions = { "json" },
});
```

Comment: Worth calling out that the extension does NOT have a period prefix.  Just wasted a couple of hours on this :(